# How to navigate with a navigation bar and a back arrow with Syncfusion and Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am creating an application where I need to navigate between 2 types of pages:

- Pages that can directly be acceded with a navigation bar with no hierarchy with the other pages.
- Pages that can only be acceded from other pages like a Master-Detail application.

The issue is that I need to keep the navigation bar in every page, and I also want to be able to go back to the previous page when I go to a page that can only be acceded from another page.

I tried to use a navigationDrawer to make the navigation bar and change its contentView when I click on an item in it for the pages with no hierarchy with the other pages, and for the pages that can only be acceded from other pages I used the Navigation.PushAsync to be able to go back to the previous page but when I do that the navigationDrawer is no longer here.

Is there a way to navigate like this with SyncFusion and Xamarin.Forms?